# OpenOffice - Macro if condition

Tags: if-statement, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I need assistance on the below simple Macro in Open Office:

--Macro to check the contents of cell A5 of the activesheet and display message

```
Sub Check
sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
value = Contents of cell A5 (Update with correct code)
If Value = "0" then Msg "All Good" Else Msgbox "Check Cell A5" EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: A good place for learning how to write macros is https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.